# C# Application that installs a c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, resources, 32bit-64bit

I made a small 32 bit C# application that installs a C++ DLL file from its resources into a folder on HD with the following C# code.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(folder + @"\test.dll", Properties.Resources.testDll);
```

It works like expected but when I'm using the dll it works partly and then crashes, but if I replace the dll installed by the 32 bit C# application with the DLL from HD that I've added from the beginning to the C# project resources, then it all works.

Why? Is it because the C# installation program is a 32 bit and the installed DLL through the resources is a 64 bit DLL??

Someone who knows how Resources 32/64 bit works?

Regards, Morgan

Comment: The bitness of the programs should be irrelevant, as all you're doing is writing some bytes to a file on disk. Whether it's a DLL, BMP, or HTML page really doesn't matter. I would suspect that somehow the DLL in the resources is corrupted. Have you hashed the original and the one written to disk, or compared them in a hex editor? If they're identical, there is no reason one should crash and the other not.

Comment: There are no breadcrumbs in this question, the code as posted should work.  There is however no lack of possibly misery when this code runs.  UAC puts a very hard stop to programs writing files in *verboten* folders like c:\program files, the normal place where you get a program installed.  Not to mention the way the user's anti-malware software is going to get excited about an executable file appearing from nowhere.  Non-zero odds that this file got quarantined, kaboom when a program tries to use it.  Don't do this, use *setup.exe*.

Comment: I've noticed now that the file was 1 320 960 bytes and became 1 321 472 bytes in size according to Windows 7 file properties.

Comment: I ended up using Inno Setup 5, and it made my problems go away. It was pretty easy to learn.